# Transform from List[Future[...] to List[...] in Scala

Tags: list, scala, seq

Is there a method (or simple way) in scala that helps to transform `List[Future[...]]`  to  `List[...]`?

If such a method is in the Seq, then it is also suitable.
I spent a lot of time looking, but I couldn't find anything. Thanks

Comment: Once you have a `Future` you have to keep it in one way or another, because otherwise you would need to await it which defeats the whole point of using it in the first place. - As the two answers suggest, you can use `Future.sequence` to transform the list of futures into a future of a list, which is easier to use. - btw, since you probably have that list of futures after using `map` you can use `Future.traverse` instead of `map` + `sequence`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sequence` can turn `List[Future[A]]` to `Future[List[A]]` and then you could await the future

```
val fxs: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(List(Future(1), Future(2)))
val xs: List[Int] = Await.result(fxs, Duration.Inf)
// work with xs
```

however usually it is preferable to map over the future instead of awaiting like so

```
fxs.map { xs: List[Int] =>
  // work with xs
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You want [Future.sequence](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#sequence%5BA,CC%5BX%5D%3C:IterableOnce%5BX%5D,To%5D(in:CC%5Bscala.concurrent.Future%5BA%5D%5D)(implicitbf:scala.collection.BuildFrom%5BCC%5Bscala.concurrent.Future%5BA%5D%5D,A,To%5D,implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BTo%5D) and then you get a Future[List[A]] which you can then decide how you want to handle.